# How do I write a query to get sqlalchemy objects from relationship?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am learning python and using the framework pyramid with sqlalchemy as the orm. I can not figure out how relationships work. I have 2 tables, offices and users. the foreign key is on the users table 'offices_id'. I am trying to do a query that will return to me what office a user is a part of.

This is how I have my models set up.

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    trec_number = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    office_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('offices.id'))

class Office(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'offices'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    address = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    members = relationship("User", backref='offices')
```

In my view how would I write a query that would return the the office information for a given user?

I am trying this:

```
for user in DBSession.query(User).join(Office).all():
    print user.address
```

but I think I am misunderstanding how the queries work because I keep getting errors

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'address'
```

when I do this:

```
 for user in DBSession.query(User).join(Office).all():
    print user.name
```

it prints out the users name fine since name is an attribute of the User class.

I also can not get the inverse to work

```
for offices in DBSession.query(Office).join(User).all():
    print offices.users.name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the name you used in the `backref` argument to access the `Office` model. Try `user.offices.address`

Comment: stackoverflow needs a buy a beer button. Thanks, worked perfectly.

Comment: Now I am stuck on doing the inverse. DBSession.query(Office).join(User).all():
offices.user.name does not work.

Comment: The attribute on the model is name members, have you tried offices.members? This should give you a list instead of a single object since it's a one-to-many relation.